# error Api key not found

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

i am trying to use google maps in my app, i am using google play services in app

MapViewActivity:

```
public class MapsViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {
// Google Map
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maps);

    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

XMl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and getting the following errors :

```
08-05 16:41:54.384: E/dalvikvm(24979): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from   method gpr.a
08-05 16:41:54.384: W/dalvikvm(24979): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
08-05 16:41:54.384: D/dalvikvm(24979): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
08-05 16:41:54.404: W/dalvikvm(24979): VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;
08-05 16:41:54.404: D/dalvikvm(24979): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
08-05 16:41:54.404: W/dalvikvm(24979): VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;
08-05 16:41:54.484: E/AndroidRuntime(24979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 16:41:54.484: E/AndroidRuntime(24979): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.example.careandcure/com.example.careandcure.MapsViewActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
08-05 16:41:54.484: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at com.example.careandcure.MapsViewActivity.onCreate(MapsViewActivity.java:16)
08-05 16:41:54.484: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
08-05 16:41:54.484: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
08-05 16:41:54.484: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
08-05 16:41:54.484: E/AndroidRuntime(24979): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
08-05 16:41:54.484: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.careandcure"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<permission
    android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.careandcure.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.careandcure.MapsViewActivity" >
    </activity>

        <!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="api_key" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

I am not getting where I am getting wrong or missing anything and
how to remove please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: android:value="my api key" ??

Comment: key i got from google console

Answer (score 0):

Clearly from your logcat, you have just copy pasted the manifest.xml file. You have to enter your **key** instead of **your API key**

Generate your key from google console. And use it in manifest.xml

You will need two metadata for version2 of googlemap

One with **api key** and another with **google service**

`android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"`

So you should simply copy paste the line. And only try to under stand later.
:-)

**Edited:**

Change the package name to yours (not of androidhive :-)) Change the line in permission

```
<permission
    android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

To:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.careandcure.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Also why are you using package name of **info.androidhive.googlemapsv2** in uses-permission. Change it to your own package name i.e. **com.example.careandcure** . Hope it's finally your solution.

Comment: i have added my own api key

Comment: See i have edited the answer. You have missed the second Metadata

Comment: Did your log cat change?

Comment: Try generating new KEY using a unique package name. Unique means something that nobody in the world might have used already. Don't use com.example.map kind of package name. And replace the old Key in Manifest with the new one

Comment: Can you once more change the manifest.xml and repost your question above?

Comment: I mean, change it to your package name instead of androidhive's example package name in manifest. I have written Edited: in my answer. See the lines after it..

Answer (score 0):

The Log say you:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

So be sure that you added it in AndroidManifest.xml like in the [guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=es):

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="API_KEY"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file error cause this line

```
<!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my api key" />
```

In value of API key you must add your own API key.

See This [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) for generate API key